# Run a python script from another python script using IF __name__ == "__main__" statement

Tags: python-2.7, module, program-entry-point

I have a script `LCP_02.py` with the if statement:

```
if __name__ == "__testcase__" or __name__ == "__main__":

    ask_costsurfacepath_path()
    ask_outputpath_path()
    CostSurfacefn = config.costsurfacepath
    startCoord = (config.startX,config.startY)
    stopCoord = (config.stopX,config.stopY)
    outputPathfn = config.outputpath
    main(CostSurfacefn,outputPathfn,startCoord,stopCoord)
```

when I run `testcase.py` (below) in the shell, it doesn't run the `LCP_02` script:

```
import config
import LCP_02

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config.startX = 356254.432
    config.startY = 5325191.299
    config.stopX = 346200.101
    config.stopY = 5301688.499
    LCP_02
```

All the functions in `LCP_02` have print statements (as a visual). But when running `testcase.py`, they are not printed. The program starts, waits around 2 seconds, and then shows the `>>>` in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons it doesn't work:

1. You imported `LCP_02`, so the `__name__` value in that module is set to `'LCP_02'`, not `'__main__'` or `'__testcase__'`. The name is *never* based on whatever imported the module.
2. Just referencing `LCP_02` on a line won't 'invoke' that module; if the guarded code was going to run, it would have done so *when importing*.

Use a function in `LCP_02` instead:

```
def run_test():
    ask_costsurfacepath_path()
    ask_outputpath_path()
    CostSurfacefn = config.costsurfacepath
    startCoord = (config.startX,config.startY)
    stopCoord = (config.stopX,config.stopY)
    outputPathfn = config.outputpath
    main(CostSurfacefn,outputPathfn,startCoord,stopCoord)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_test()
```

and call that function from your `testcase.py` module:

```
LCP_02.run_test()
```